# JSON/AJAX and Facebook

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, facebook, json

I'm currently creating a facebook fan page (www.facebook.com.SSBMstream), and I am using a static html app to create a section that will allow users to select a twitch.tv stream they wish to watch using a button. I want to go one step further and list channels based on whether or not they are 'live' or offline. Twitchtv/Justintv already has an api set up for exactly that (http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=) where you can just plug in the channel name and get '[]' if it is not live and what I believe is JSON if it is. How to dynamically check each channel in my array to determine if it is live and, if possible, access the information in that api to allow me to update titles and the like?

EDIT: Here's the hollowed out version of my code (Only the part I'm having trouble with)
I'm having it return the information from the other page as a debugger so I can test whether or not (if/when) it's working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadJSON()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=ignproleague",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Just a test</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadJSON()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how twitch defines what is live and what isn't. Sorry I'm not super familiar with twitch's API but if it returns an empty array if the channel isn't live you could simply check `if (array.length == 0)`.

If you are given a JSON object, then just interact with the appropriate information you need. I don't know exactly how twitch formats their JSON objects but here is an example. Let's say it returned this JSON object:

```
var JSONobj = {
"channelName": "e-sports", "channelTheme: "Professional Gaming", "viewerCount": 100 
};
```

To retrieve the information you would just have to call the appropriate field.

```
var chan = JSONobj.channelName; //chan = "e-sports
var theme = JSONobj.channelTheme; //theme = "Professional Gaming"
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: It seems you need help with understanding AJAX. Let me just give you a rough idea of what the syntax is. I personally use a framework called [Prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/)

```
new Ajax.Request(WEB_SERVICE, {
    method: "get",
    parameters: {"type" : type, "name" : name},
    onSuccess: successCall,
    onFailure: ajaxError,
    onException: ajaxError
});
```

This is your pretty typical AJAX request. When this is called, it'll throw an AJAX request to a WEB_SERVICE (generally a PHP document that will get the parameters passed and then calculate something from it). In this scenario the method being passed is "GET" and the parameters being passed is in the form of an object with the fields "type" and "name".  successCall is a method that is called when the AJAX request successfully is passed and returns the ajax that has been calculated. I'm assuming in your scenario your AJAX should be receiving some information in a JSON format so its important your successCall function not only gets back that information, but parses through it as if it were JSON. Your successCall function would look something like this:

```
function successCall(ajax) {
    var info = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
```

Hopefully from here you have a good understanding of what's going on. Try to work with this and if you still need help, just comment.

Oh and I didn't see that other comment. If you want to MAKE a JSON object you can do so like this.

```
var JSONobj = {};
JSONobj.field = something;
```

Your JSON object would then look something like this:

```
JSONobj = { "field" : something };
```

It is important you stringify the JSONobj if you want to pass it as a String. I guess it depends on how your WEB_SERVICE is handling it and you can do so like this.

```
var stringJSON = JSON.stringify(JSONobj);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem lies before I even get to that point. I'm not having success with reading the webpage using AJAX, I'm not familiar enough with AJAX to figure out my problem. I've read through many AJAX tutorials but they are all either about php or a site on the same domain. Nothing about cross domain without being about to use certain apis (I don't seem to be able to include any on facebook).

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if cross-site AJAX is possible after what I've just read, but I know that if I use the <form> object in html I can read the data and have it display on my page. What I want is to be able to read the data without a user input and store the data in a json object so I can reference it later.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't look like the html app in facebook supports Ajax.Request, or at least it doesn't show up in blue when I type it in. Alternatively, I tried using the older method of xmlhttprequest, but the response from the address is always null. I.E. It doesn't show anything and the stringified results is "". I'll edit my original post with the code I guess.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the AJAX method I used uses a framework known as [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/). I'll try to find an AJAX answer that doesn't require that method (this was the way I learned it at school). If you'd like, maybe you can try linking your code to that js file but I'll look for another way.

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that a few times, but I think the fact that it's facebook causes some issues on that end. To my knowledge, you cannot include any external files.